# Как подключить DatePicker Yii2

Tags: yii2

По этой ссылке все выполнил, https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget
установил пакеты через composer, пробую в форме подключать

```
<?php

 use yii\helpers\Html;
 use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
 use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;

 echo DatePicker::widget([
   'name'  => 'from_date',
   'value'  => $value,
   //'language' => 'ru',
   //'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
 ]); ?>
```

Выдает такую ошибку

```
Class 'dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker' not found
```

пробовал так же  https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html
Все та же ошибка...

Comment: тоже на дня перестал работать DatePicker, хотя до этого норм работал, оказалось меня шаблон и отключил jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня в composer.json обозначено     "minimum-stability": "stable" и выдает ошибку:
The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting.

И по каждой версии пакета 2amigos/datepicker пишет "no matching package found".

Проверил ли ты, что дейтпикер действительно установился?
Именно поэтому может всплывать данная ошибка.
У меня в каталоге vendor/2amigos/src ни одного DatePicker класса нету. Не установился из-за ошибки.

Возможно стоит использовать описанный в доке пикер
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html

Comment: Побывал уже три разных подключать везде одна и та же ошибка.... сразу складывается не очень положительное впечатление  о Yii2 (((

Comment: На фреймворк сетовать не стоит :) Что тебе пишет при установке через композер? Удали пикер и установи еще раз и опубликуй сообщение после инсталляции дейтпикера. И проверь, что у тебя действительно установлен каталог vendor/2amigos/src. У меня в этой директории видимо из-за ошибки ни одного дейтпикер класса нету. Только TinyMCE.

Comment: А вот kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker у меня работает отлично.

Comment: ничего не работает все тоже самое

Answer (score 2):

В `composer.json` попробуй поставить:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

А также проверь секцию `require` на наличие:

```
"2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget" : "~1.0",
```

После запусти `composer update`.

У меня поставилось и работает.

Также можешь посмотреть на аналог:
https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker